# Null Pointer Exception on result

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

In my app you you tap a button that launches the Gallery. You select an image and then crop that image into a square (1:1). on the result of that crop it saves the image and pushes the uri to a new intent which displays the image in an ImageView (pretty simple). It works about 30% of the time though and I can't find any similarities in crashes. It seems like after I load it onto my device to debug it crashes the first 2 times I launch and works the 3rd time. I'm very confused on this if anyone can help me understand this that would be great! My idea is maybe to much is happening onResult and my intent to jump to another class is getting fired before it can complete it's other task. Also I'm new to coding so please bear with my sloppy code.

Logcat:

```
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.yourboytyler.shoutgram/com.yourboytyler.shoutgram.go}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=file:///mnt/sdcard/SHOUTgram/pic_1347297141912.jpg (has extras) }} to activity {com.yourboytyler.shoutgram/com.yourboytyler.shoutgram.go}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=file:///mnt/sdcard/SHOUTgram/pic_1347297141912.jpg (has extras) }} to activity {com.yourboytyler.shoutgram/com.yourboytyler.shoutgram.go}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     ... 12 more
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at com.yourboytyler.shoutgram.go.onActivityResult(go.java:163)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3934)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
09-10 11:12:55.291: E/AndroidRuntime(2608):     ... 13 more
```

Code:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,  
            int resultCode, Intent data) { 
            //Activity.RESULT_OK
            if (resultCode == -1) {  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mUri.getPath(), //THIS IS LINE 163
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                b1.setEnabled(true);
                ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i1);
                Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("file://" + mUri.getPath());
                imgView.setImageURI(imgUri);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("uripic", mUri.toString());
                editor.commit();


                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                        new String[] { goldburg.toString() }, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
               });




                Intent openConnectPoint2 = new Intent("com.my.pakage.NAME"); //changed for privacy
                startActivity(openConnectPoint2);  
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {  
            b1.setEnabled(true);
                return; 
             }



            if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {  
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);  
            // here you have to pass absolute path to your file  
            intent.putExtra("image-path", mUri.getPath());  
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);  
            startActivity(intent);  
        }  



        }
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException ... at com.yourboytyler.shoutgram.go.onActivityResult(go.java:163)` I would prefer to see which line is 163. (In Eclipse use Ctrl+L to jump to a specific line.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Sam line 163 is the Toast line. Which is directly after the if resultCode == -1. (I commented in my code to help you find it)

Comment: Is right for me to assume I can use -1 in place of Activity.RESULT_OK? it didn't seem to make a difference, still got random launch time crashes.

Comment: A null pointer exception is caused when you attempt to call a method, like `.getPath()`, on a variable that is `null`. Odds are `mUri` is null, double check where you set `mUri = ...`.

Comment: Yeah I guess that must be the problem. mUri is the URI of the newly created image after it's cropped. As to why it works sometimes and not other times still confuses me but I will look more closely at that variable thank you Sam!

Comment: After tweaking some things I got it work correctly every time it's launched. Turns out you were right mUri was still null while I was trying to make a call to it. Defining your variables as something before you use them makes things run a little smoother (: haha thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Brought up from comments**

The most important information from your LogCat is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.yourboytyler.shoutgram.go.onActivityResult(go.java:163)
```

And you indicated that this is line 163:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mUri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I would guess that `mUri` is `null`, but as you stated, only sometimes. A null pointer exception is caused when you attempt to call a method, like `.getPath()`, on a variable that is `null`. So double check where you set `mUri = ...`