# Does anyone have a cropImage example for Android?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, crop

I have an Android app that I have been working on and I have been using the built in Crop Image Intent (using the Gallery) to crop pictures. I need to allow the user to crop an image as a square (1:1) and then I will later manipulate the image. Here's my problem: For some reason complete out of my understanding the app Force Closes and returns with a NullPointerException... Sometimes. This happens when trying to retrieve the URI from the newly created (cropped) image. It happens at such random times that it's starting to make me wonder if its just a OME manifesting itself in a weird way. Anyway I'm totally lost and have have already asked this question with no real answer (other than what a NullPointerException is), which didn't help. I posted my question here: [Link to previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356942/android-programming-null-pointer-exception-on-result)

If you could answer with any advice that would be awesome, otherwise I'm giving up on the standard Gallery Crop and going to write my own crop method. I'm fairly new to programming so if you guys could suggest any examples or code snippets of a "custom crop activity" that would be awesome.

PS. I'm looking for a method similar to Instagrams crop method. Do you think this is something a somewhat newbie like me could do? or would that take lots of expertise?

Answer (score 1):

this will open the selection window asking from what kind of gallery you need to pickup the image (will show you the options and apps available for that) and once you select one, it will show you the crop screen.

I hope it helps!...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);

Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/yourTempDirectory/"));
intent.setData(imageUri);
intent.setType("image/*.");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200); 
intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

try {       
    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_CAPTURE);
}catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("ERROR!!!! :  ",""+e);
}
```

Important! you must declare

```
final int GALLERY_CAPTURE = 1;
```

Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source Android library that works pretty well, it's called [CropImage](https://github.com/alecio/cropimage), give it a try.